# Sequelize - Error many relations with the same name foreignKey - MyModel.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When I compile my node app trying to put many relations in my model class, I get this error

```
MyModel.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
```

This is my model class **Poll.js**:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../database/database'
import Catchment from './Catchment'
import Question from './Question'

const Poll = sequelize.define('polls', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    enabled: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    },
    created_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    }
},{
    timestamps: false
})

Poll.hasMany(Question, { foreignKey: { name:'poll_id', unique: false}, as: 'questions' })
Poll.hasMany(Catchment, { foreignKey: { name:'poll_id', unique: false}, as: 'catchments' })

export default Poll
```

**Question.js**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../database/database'
import Poll from './Poll';

const Question = sequelize.define('questions', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    poll_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    created_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    }
},{
    timestamps: false
})

Question.belongsTo(Poll, { foreignKey: { name:'poll_id', unique: false}, as: 'poll' })

export default Question
```

**Catchment.js**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'
import { sequelize } from '../database/database'
import Poll from './Poll'

const Catchment = sequelize.define('catchments', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    poll_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    created_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: false
})

Catchment.belongsTo(Poll, { foreignKey: { name: 'poll_id', unique: false }, as: 'poll' })

export default Catchment
```

The schema is:

- a Poll (has many)-> Questions
- a Poll (has many)-> Catchments

I think it can be because they have the same name of foreignKey: poll_id, thanks

Comment: please share the schema definition of the problem model

Comment: the same foreign key is not the issue - we need to see the schema of the other models and the relevant query that is causing the problem

Comment: @SamuelG thanks, when I compile the node app the problem appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is the circular dependency you have between the modules. You are obviously requiring them in sequence and the relevant models cannot all be available like that.

Define your models and export **without** the associations, then create the associations once the models have been defined.

For example:

```
// create the model definitions
const User = require('./user');
const Department = require('./department');

// now that you have the model definitions, create the associations
User.belongsTo(Department, {foreignKey: 'department_id'});
Department.hasMany(User, {foreignKey: 'department_id'});

// or like the below as the models should now exist on sequelize.models
sequelize.models.user.belongsTo(sequelize.models.department, {foreignKey: 'department_id'});
sequelize.models.department.hasMany(sequelize.models.user, {foreignKey: 'department_id'});
```

Comment: Thanks, I defined my models first, after that,  I created the associations

Comment: Yes, first export the models, and then export the associations